# NoClassDefFoundError , what is overlooked here? (image attached)

Tags: java, android, adt, noclassdeffounderror

Symptom: I am using a project I pulled from the creator's git repository. I included their libraries, as seen in the `libs` folder. The project has no errors, the project compiles. Yet when it accesses an object that is supposed to be in the jar it crashes.

I've done some other suggestions that I've read here. I've read something about changing the `classpath` , where is that?

Also, the src code for the jar shows the object in question as actually existing....

`ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();`

```
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at com.pigmal.android.ex.twitter4j.TwitterApp.askOAuth(TwitterApp.java:110)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at com.pigmal.android.ex.twitter4j.TwitterApp.onClick(TwitterApp.java:144)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2482)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9077)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at a ndroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-30 11:26:16.878: E/AndroidRuntime(11098):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my complete project setup. The fact that this is using Android is probably not relevant here, I don't want to alienate Java experts by tagging it Android

[image]

Comment: 1) Saying "Android" won't alienate "Java experts" ;)  2) The IDE's "Java Build Path" *is* the compile-time and run-time "CLASSPATH". Q: What exactly is "the object in question"?  Q: Could you please post the *exact error*?

Comment: @paulsm4 I usually don't tag android posts with Java, so some java only guys might not see questions that are android related. I updated with the exact error

Comment: How are you running the application (command line, eclipse, etc..)? Any arguments passed in?

Comment: not missing arguments, the project gets compiled and packaged and is run on an android device. I think its more related to the way the files are referenced? But the project has no errors

Comment: Not sure if this might be the problem -- Have you added the jars in the libs folder as External Libraries in the "Properties" of your android project?

Comment: @cklab did the screenshot load for you? because thats exactly what it is a picture of...

Comment: Oh nope, it appears they do not load for me. Good to know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved it for me http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

```
What I did to fix the bug was :

Remove the libraries from the standard Java build path :
Right click on the project name > Properties > Java Build Path > tab Libraries > remove      everything except the “Android X.X” (2.3.3 in my case) and the “Android Dependencies”
Rename the libraries folder from “lib” to “libs”
By doing that, all the libraries in the folder “libs” are found by the Android plugin and   are added to the “Android Dependencies” item of the project
Restart Eclipse
Android Dependencies should be created. Running the app won't produce NoClassDefFoundError anymore
```

with the exception being that I had to RESTART ECLIPSE after following these instructions, instead of merely cleaning the project afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this worked from me.

1. go to the Build Path, remove the twitter4j libraries, and do Ok.
2. go to the Build Path, select the Add External Libraries, then go to the project folder which you downloaded from the github, then go to its lib folder, you will find the twitter4j files there, select the twitter4j-core only (but only and only if it still fails include the twitter4j-stream too, until then keep the core only) and do Ok.

Comment: Good advice!  CQM - Eclipse "build path" == Java "classpath".  Unfortunately, there are two different build paths/class paths involved: 1) compile-time, and 2) runtime.  Your problem is that the runtime classpath isn't picking up the .jar that has class "twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder".  You must add the .jars as "External Libraries".

Comment: This seems to put me back at square one. No errors, it compiles, but upon running the app it crashes with the `NoClassDefFoundError` when it accesses a method. What project were you using that twitter4j-core was the only one you needed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, removing all twitter libraries from the build path and renaming the lib folder to libs solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you better tag android also for this question. I have seen people on earlier posts having similar issues even because of ADT version. Ideally, since you have put your code inside `libs` folder, you should be able to get all those classes. But this seems to be some runtime issue and not compile time.

Also this seems to be specific to android.

---

Have you manually added jar in classpath?
Normally, when a jar is added in `libs` folder, it start appearing inside `Android Dependencies` and not directly as shown in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

For me rename the folder, and restarting didn't solve the problem. But, inside [a pages with links posted in a previous comment](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17), there is an answer the one who solved my problem.
This response says:

`If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references.
To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.`

And i must move twitter jar before src folder